# RUSLE3d parameter and validation

Tags: grass-gis

I am a graduate student in remote sensing studying soil erosion.
  I'm very new to GRASS GIS software. I don't want to use North Carolina data.
I also read the software homepage. Do you have any information on building watershed and getting RUSLE 3D parameters? How do I validate this parameter?

Comment: Maybe this presentation is useful: Mezzini, E., Antisari, L. V., Ventura, F., Magnan, F. (2015): RUSLE model application with GRASS GIS: Rio Centonara catchment. FOSS4G Europe 2015, 14-17 Jul 2015, Como, Italy, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B46kztqdEkOHUnlyZWZzUllPM2s/view

Comment: it was very useful.thank you. do you know about ProNEVA model?can you  help me